# Passing PHP variable into Javascript String for embedded Vimeo Link

Tags: php, javascript, video, vimeo

I'm trying to pass a PHP variable from Wordpress custom field into a javascript string.
The custom field contains the ID number for a Vimeo video and it needs to be place in the middle the the string thats replacing an image on click. Here's the code:

```
jQuery("#index-image").click(function(){

    jQuery(this).replaceWith('<div id="video-container"><iframe id="videoframe" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/"<?php echo $page_videos[$i]; ?>"color=ffffff&portrait=0&byline=0&title=0&autoplay=1&api=1&player_id=videoframe" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%;" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>');
```

Creating an alert for the string as a variable returns the correct string with the ID number of the video, however the browser only generates the string without the PHP variable.

Not sure what to do. I've tried assembling the string using variables and putting it into the replaceWith function but am having no luck anywhere.

Please help.

Comment: Verify that `$page_videos[$i]` is not empty. Because as long as you have PHP installed, `<?php echo $page_videos[$i]; ?>` will work.

Comment: I've built out the string into variables and created an alert that returned the correct string. The browser seems to not be acknowledging the variable at all in the html. It returns the string without the variable in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the variable is being echoed outside of the src attribute.

```
    jQuery(this).replaceWith('<div id="video-container"><iframe id="videoframe" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo $page_videos[$i]; ?>&color=ffffff&portrait=0&byline=0&title=0&autoplay=1&api=1&player_id=videoframe" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%;" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>');
```

Comment: How so? 
`http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo $page_videos[$i]; ?>&color=ffffff&portrait=0&byline=0&title=0&autoplay=1&api=1&player_id=videoframe` 
that's the entire src link

Comment: In you question post the php echo was encased in double quotes. Which would break the source attribute before the php echo of ID

Comment: What does var_dump($page_videos) return?